# "payment_method_nonce" returning an empty string in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, braintree, braintree-sandbox

I'm trying to create a simple transaction using Braintree in sandbox mode. It requires me to make a POST request method from the page in order to continue making the transaction. The developer docs however, does not tell what should I do next after I successfully rendered the Drop-in UI.

From what I know, in order to sucessfully make a POST request, the inputs need to have the "name" attribute in its HTML code. Logically, it should have the name "payload_method_nonce" in one of the inputs. But since it isn't there, some users suggested to add a code like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce">
```

in order to do this in PHP:

```
$nonceFromTheClient = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"]
```

and add these few lines of code:

```
var form = document.querySelector('#payment_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
document.querySelector('input[name="payment_method_nonce"]').value = 
payload.nonce;
  form.submit();
});
}, false);
```

I've already did that but it still returns nothing.

What should I do?

Full codes:

HTML

```
<form id="payment-form">
<div id="dropin-container"></div>
      <input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce">
      <button id="submit-button" class="w3-theme-action submit-btn" 
style="width: 27.5%; margin-bottom: 16px; margin-left: 0;">Request 
payment method</button>
</form>
<script>
var button = document.querySelector('#submit-button');

braintree.dropin.create({
  authorization: 'xxxxxx',
  container: '#dropin-container'
}, function (createErr, instance) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
      // Submit payload.nonce to your server
var form = document.querySelector('#payment_form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
  document.querySelector('input[name="payment_method_nonce"]').value = 
payload.nonce;
  form.submit();
});
}, false);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
$nonceFromTheClient = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"]
echo $nonceFromTheClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

The default method for an HTML form is `GET`.

Either change your form method:

```html
<form id="payment-form" method="POST"> ... </form>
```

Or access your data into `$_GET`:

```php
$nonceFromTheClient = $_GET["payment_method_nonce"];
```